# Is there any way to capture logs while using Android MonkeyRunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am trying to capture the logs and find out the status of the Bluetooth.
The logs should be captured and using it I must be able to print results accordingly.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: You didn't tell what problems you have found or what you attempted.